# prepareforsegue enters infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am saving an image in my ViewController, and want to pass it to the next one during segue, however doing this causes an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"next"])
    {
        ReviewViewController *rvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [rvc setFilename:self.filename];
    }
}
```

the `setFilename` method in `ReviewViewController` simply looks like this:

```
- (void)setFilename:(NSString *)filename{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Setting filename to: %@",filename]);
    self.filename = filename;
}
```

That log statement fires off ad-infinitum when I add in the `prepareForSegue` method. If I remove it, the transition is fine.

What is going on?

Comment: NSLog already is a formatted String:
    NSLog(@"Setting filename to: %@",filename);

Comment: @JörnBuitink Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your setFilename method is causing the recursion as you are calling `self.filename = filename` which effectively calls the `setFilename:` method. Try `_filename = filename;` instead.

Comment: @Rog That fixed it. Can you post as an answer with a bit more detail as to why that assignment wasn't working? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. The problem is because `self.filename = filename` calls `setFileName:`, and so on... You need to write as Rog said.

Comment: Hi Tom I won't post it as an answer as there must be dozens of similar questions here. The bottom line is that `self.filename = ABC` is equivalent to `[self setFilename:ABC]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as many pointed out in the comments, is that `self.filename =` actually calls `[self setFilename]`, which is what I had called my method.

This is fixed by either renaming my `setFilename` method, or doing the assignment via `_filename =` instead.